# Video link for registered users

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, video, amazon-s3

I have a website in which we are now uploading course contents. I now want only authenticated users to access these contents. The video links should not open for other users. My server is on django on aws ec2 instance. How to achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

You tagged the question with S3 so I'm going to assume you are hosting the videos on S3. You should generate an [S3 pre-signed URL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) on your Django server whenever a user wants to view a video. This will give the user's browser a time-limited URL to the video.